# Dynamic login/logout URLs in Django

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I have an app that serves pages like this /stage/*stagename*. *stagename* is variable. The URL mappers just look for a [0-9A-Za-z]+ to fill that slot.

Now, because of my setup, My app will be rooted at /stage/*stagename*. I cannot change this (without massive changes to my setup which is too tedious right now and a last option).

I need to use `django.contrib.auth`. The login and logout URLs can't be in my settings file since they will change depend on where my app is rooted (For one it might be /stage/foo/login and for the other, it might might /stage/bar/login).

How can I make the backend use such dynamic URLs?

I also have the issue that I need to pass the *stagename* parameter to the template which generates my URL. How can I do that?

Comment: "massive changes to my setup which is too tedious right now and a last option"  A very bad sign.  Very, very bad.  You should probably stop what you're doing.  Throw this away and begin again.  Starting fresh might be less expensive than pressing forward.

Comment: I agree and I do have a branch of the code where I've half fixed my mistakes. However, I have a deadline which I need to meet right now and have no option but to get this working somehow.

Comment: "get this working somehow".  Sometimes beginning again is faster than pressing forward.

Comment: Not this time though I generally agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get `redirect_to` into the context for your login template, then there is a mechanism you can use to choose vary the redirect URL.

In your login template, add an extra hidden input to the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url redirect_to %}">
```

Now in your urls.py file, you can specify what input to use for the redirect:

```
url(r'^login/$',
    auth_views.login,
    {'template_name': 'registration/login.html',
     'redirect_field_name': 'next'},
    name='auth_login'),
```

If you do this, then you'll be redirected to different places depending on the value of `redirect_to`.

You might be able to get `redirect_to` into your context by having more than one named login url:

```
url(r'^login/$',
    auth_views.login,
    {'template_name': 'registration/login.html',
     'redirect_field_name': 'next',
     'extra_context': {'redirect_to': 'foo_url'}
    },
    name='foo_login'),

url(r'^login/$',
    auth_views.login,
    {'template_name': 'registration/login.html',
     'redirect_field_name': 'next',
     'extra_context': {'redirect_to': 'bar_url'}
    },
    name='bar_login'),
```

Or if you don't want to do that sort of thing, you could use something in the session instead:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url session.redirect_to %}">
```

Hope this helps, and apologies if there are typos in the code! The documentation for the auth login view is a bit hard to link to [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.views). Go to that link and scroll up a bit!

Answer (score 0):

> /stage/foo/login and for the other, it might might /stage/bar/login).

```
url( r'^stage/(?P<name>[^/]+)/login/$', some_view_function )
```

Might be what you're looking for.

However, you seem to have bigger problems than this.  "massive changes to my setup which is too tedious" indicates more serious and fundamental problems.

Comment: I have something like this but I can't put this in my `settings.py`. It has to be hardcoded there.

Comment: That's not supposed to be in your settings.py.  That's supposed to be in your urls.py.  What are you doing?

Comment: `LOGIN_URL = '/login'` in the `settings.py` to give it the URL to which it should redirect to present the login form. I'm using a slightly older version of Django for which I can't pass the `login_url` parameter to the decorator.